# Generating a filled array in javascript

Tags: javascript

Why does this code produce an array of 20 elements which are all undefined:

```
> Array(20).map(function() { return 3; })
[ , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,  ]
```

Whereas this code produces an array of 20 elements which are all 3s:

```
> Array(20).join(' ').split(' ').map(function() { return 3; })
[ 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 ]
```

Why does the first approach not behave as expected?

Comment: `map` does omit holes.